# Display form again after submit

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to display a form multiple times in codeigniter. My goal is to have a user fill a form about themselves, and then proceed to another page to input information about family members. The number of family members will be specified in the 1st form. i did the following, but all instances of the form are appearing on the same page, with multiple submit buttons.

Here is the controller function

```
public function register_relation_famille(){
   for ($i=1; $i<=3; $i++){
        //validation rules

             if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
                $data['main_view'] = 'users/relation3/famille';
                $this->load->view('layouts/main', $data);
            } else { 
                if($this->user_model->create_relation_famille()){
                    $this->session->set_userdata('filled', 'Filled');
                    $data['main_view'] = 'home_view';
                    $this->load->view('layouts/main', $data);
                } else {
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('user_not_registered', 'User has not been registred');
                    redirect('home/index');
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

My Model

```
public function create_relation_famille(){  
    $data = array(

        'demande_id'        =>$this->session->userdata('user_id'),
        'nom'               =>$this->input->post('nom'),
        'prenom'            =>$this->input->post('prenom'),
        'fonction'  =>$this->input->post('fonction_groupe'),
        'relation'          =>$this->input->post('relation'),
        'membre_groupe'     =>$this->input->post('membre_group'),
        'annee_service'     =>$this->input->post('annee_service')
    );

        $insert_data = $this->db->insert('relations1', $data);

        return $insert_data;

}
```

And i have my form which contains 5 fields and a submit button.
  Can anyone help ?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use  jQuery to load different forms on a page. JQuery can be used to hide/show html elements.

`$("#Form1").show();
$("#Form2").hide();`

It's simpler if you use Jquery.

Comment: @samerc if it helped you, Vote it up or mark the answer as correct :)